# willpopscope, The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Future<bool>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was trying to make willpopscope, but I don't know whats going on here

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return SelectKoas();
      }));
    },
    child: new Scaffold(
    
    ),
  );
}
```

here is the error

`error: The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Future<bool>', as required by the closure's context. (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure at [gigimu_koas] lib\LoginKoas.dart:52)`

Comment: Not 100% sure, but try adding a bool type argument `MaterialPageRoute<bool>(...)`.

Comment: can you show what SelectKoas() is?

Answer (score 1):

```
    @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return WillPopScope(
           onWillPop: () async {
             return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
               return SelectKoas();
             }));
            return Future.value(true); //this line will help
           },
           child: new Scaffold(
           
           ),
         );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates `onWillPop` takes a `Future<bool>` function. So on your class level:

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
         return SelectKoas();
       }));
    return true;
}
```

Then

```
return WillPopScope(
       onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      ),
```